# In vim, background color changes on scrolling

Tags: vim, colors, vimrc

Occasionally I get a weird error with the background color in vim when scrolling up in a long file. The background over the text is correct, but everywhere there is no printable character the background turns black.

After a bit of hunting and experimenting, I have found that :redraw! fixes the problem, but I would like to know why this occurs and if there is anything I can do to permanently fix the issue.

Although I have gotten this error to occur with other color schemes, for what it is worth I am using the lucius color scheme with vim 7.3 editing a bunch of python files.

Comment: I've done a bit more playing, and it seems to happen only when I have my terminal geometry set with a height larger than 30 or so. I'll have to do more testing to see if this holds, but maybe that information will help someone figure out what is wrong...

Comment: Here is an example screenshot of this behavior. I scrolled up and instead of the lovely grayish background, there is some ugly black stuff.

[screenshot](http://i48.tinypic.com/2zgaesw.png)

Comment: Have you tried several different terminal emulators (like xterm, gnome-terminal, etc.)?

Comment: I've managed to reproduce the behavior in both lxterminal and gnome-terminal.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Mine started to happen when i moved stuff to ftplugin/<filetype>...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As explained [here](http://snk.tuxfamily.org/log/vim-256color-bce.html) and [here](https://github.com/sunaku/.vim/blob/config/config/color.vim#L11-L16), you can fix this by turning off `Background Color Erase`. Change in your `.vimrc`:

```
if &term =~ '256color'
    " Disable Background Color Erase (BCE) so that color schemes
    " work properly when Vim is used inside tmux and GNU screen.
    set t_ut=
endif
```

You can also type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to reset the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a plugin or configuration related, perhaps try

> vim -u NONE

to load vim without the vimrc and without plugins and see if the problem persists.

As far as configuration, I think you should probably look at lazyredraw and ttyfast.

You can read the documetation by typing (:help lazyredraw) and find out if you've unknowingly set it (:set lazyredraw?) and probably unset it (:set nolazyredraw).

And it may help if you set ttyfast (:help ttyfast).

Comment: I tried both nolazyredraw and ttyfast, but the behavior remains the same.

Comment: @jlund3 I've edited my answer a little bit.

Comment: With -u NONE there are no colors for this to happen. However, with just the command :colorscheme lucius it still happens...